# How to stop zombies from spawning in my torch-lit mines?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My mines are filled with torches, properly lit, but zombies keep spawning there. I left the ladder exposed and they ambushed me from behind killing my dude. How do I stop it from happening?

Comment: One thing. LAVA ALL OVER.

Answer (score 7):

Several things could cause this. There could be a slightly-too-dark corner in your tunnels or an overlooked side passage. If the light level drops to 7 or lower in any square, you need more torches.

In order to ensure >7 light in all areas, you need torches every 12 meters (blocks) in all directions. However, note that if your tunnel is more than 1 block wide, simply placing a torch on the wall every 12 blocks will result in a square that has less than 8 light at the midpoint on the opposite side of the hall. My recommendation is to be excessive in your lighting and place a lot of torches.

Comment: I don't think the devices that the Pocket editions of the game run on have F3 available to them.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked the "pocket-edition" part of the tag. In that case your only option is to go crazy with the torches.

Comment: I didnt go crazy with the torches I lit every square dag gummit.

Comment: While every square may be "lit", this does not ensure that no monsters will spawn. As I said, each square must have a light level of at least 8 to ensure no monsters will spawn in it. Try adding some extra torches in the dimmer parts and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: I did that yesterday came back there again after 10 nights and it's like a underground zombie party

Comment: Each square had a zombie on it

Comment: Once spawned a zombie can move into a lit square.  Thus that doesn't indicate that they're spawning in lit squares.  All it takes is one square without enough light.

Answer (score 4):

This was actually a bug in v0.3.3 and below, [as described in the MCPE forum](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition_issues#Bugs_6). It has been fixed in the 0.4.0 release.

From the [0.4.0 release notes:](http://www.mojang.com/2012/09/minecraft-pocket-edition-0-4-0-is-out/#more-1824)

> Bug fixes:

> - ```
>   Monsters could spawn indoors
>   ```

To test I have ventured back into my open-plan underground mine (something like 40x40 wide and full of torches ever 4 blocks or so) which always used to spawn mobs at one end whenever I was at the other and have not seen any mobs in there since the upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

Probably there could be dark spaces in your tunnel, but if you left your tunnel exposed to the outside world then that's probably how mobs got in. But like you said, they spawned so the mobs probably spawned there because there could be dark spaces as I said, but also maybe you put your torches in the wrong spots. If yours is properly lit, everything nice, then maybe it's a bug, or something minecraft has possible for mobs to do, like breaking doors now in pc. If this keeps happening to you, I prefer you cover it up and dig somewhere else, but don't just leave your torches there, get it. Make your tunnel start indoors maybe in your house, but also, I prefer making a treehouse high, like 10 blocks or higher, to prevent creepers from exploding and destroying your house, and to prevent mobs from chasing you around. I hope this helps. :)

Source(s):
Me, I play a lot and I'm a minecraft pe expert.